# Geolocation in React Native iOS

Tags: react-native

I am trying to access navigator.geolocation in my application.

I have also set "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" in my info.plist.

But, when I run my app, It throws an error saying "undefined is not an object (evaluating navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition)" .

Here is my code -

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Navigator,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay'
var GiftedSpinner = require('react-native-gifted-spinner');
var GLOBAL = require('./Globals');
var stateName;
var latitude;
var longitude;

class PersonByLocationPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.data = this.props.data;

     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                        (position) => {
                           var crd = position.coords;
                           latitude = crd.latitude;
                           longitude = crd.longitude;
                            // alert(latitude);
                            // alert(longitude);
                          },
                          (error) => alert(error.message),
                          {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
                      );


    this.REQUEST_URL = 'sample';


    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      loaded: false,
      networkError: false,
    };
  }
```

Can anybody tell what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: If you have debugged, could you check which object in the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is undefined ? Is it navigator or navigator.geolocation ?

Comment: Hi, I dont know what was the issue. Now, it is running perfectly. And, I have no idea why ?

Comment: And now, It is showing the same error when I am running app in device.

Comment: When I debug, it goes into error function of navigator and gives error "Unable to retrieve location."

Comment: Now, It is working when I am debugging. But, when I disable the debugging,  it again shows the same error "undefined"

Comment: Can you share code on github or something else?

Comment: I have shared the code here only. I guess the problem is not in code. Otherwise, it would not be running while debugging.

Comment: Any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

1. Drag RCTGeolocation.xcodeproj into the Libraries folder.
2. Click on your project in the project navigator.
3. Click YOUR_PROJECT_NAME under TARGETS.
4. Click the Build Phases tab. In the Link Binary With Libraries phase,
5. click the plus icon and select libRCTGeolocation.a
   from the modal list that appears.

That should be all you need. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in Xcode

and

libRCTGeolocation.a in Xcode

you can find how to add library from
http://www.slideshare.net/kobkrit/reactnative-tutorial-10-camera-roll-gallery-camera-native-modules-by-making-selfies-scoreboard-apps