# Wrong Geolocation with React Native and iOS simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, apple-maps, react-native-maps

I am working with react-native-maps and using the react-native api for geolocation. When I am using location through the api what comes back on the simulator shows me in San Francisco not in Denver, CO where I am located. Is there a reason as to why my location would not show where I am at?

my function that runs the location

```
  // Get current users locaiton on load
  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      console.log(position);
      let newLat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
      console.log("newLat", newLat);
      let newLng = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);
      console.log("newLng", newLng);
      // set region of user to lat and long position
      // deltas set distance from marker (zoom) on map
      this.setState({
        region: {
          latitude: newLat,
          longitude: newLng,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0250,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0125
        },
        error: null
      });
      console.log(this.state);
    }, 
      // if error set state with error
      (err) => {
        console.log(err),
        // set location accuracy on
        // max time to find location in 5 sec
        // max time to use cached location for phone 5 sec
        { timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 5000 };
      }
    );

    // watch for changes and update location
    this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
      console.log(position);
      let newLat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
      console.log("newLat", newLat);
      let newLng = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);
      console.log("newLng", newLng);
      // set region of user to lat and long position
      // deltas set distance from marker (zoom) on map
      this.setState({
        region: {
          latitude: newLat,
          longitude: newLng,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0250,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0125
        },
        error: null
      });
      console.log(this.state);
    },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err),
        // set location accuracy on
        // max time to find location in 5 sec
        // max time to use cached location for phone 5 sec
        // distance before location called again 10 m
        { timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 5000, distanceFilter: 10 }
      }
    );
  }
```

my location preset in initial state is :

```
this.state ={
      region: {
          latitude: 39.739236,
          longitude: -104.990251,
          latitudeDelta: 0.1000,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0500
      },
```

which is relatively closer than where the iOS simulator shows me at
[image: console log of my location]

anyone run into this problem and know how to solve it? Is it the network that react-native is running on or shouldn't it be pulling from my laptops network location?

I have looked to see if anyone else ran into this issue:
[Geolocation in React Native iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996054/geolocation-in-react-native-ios?s=2|2.0605)
and the search on stack only shows 6 results if you search for geolocation wrong react-native ios...google wasn't much help either.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is the correct behavior on the iOS simulator (and the Android emulator). You can change the mocked coordinates for geolocation on each like so (paraphrased from other answers):

**[iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819312/how-to-test-geolocation-on-simulator)**

1. Run app in iOS simulator.
2. At the top menu bar, you'll find Features -> Location -> Custom Location..(or you can choose to use others).
3. Set the Latitude & Longitude for the location.

**[Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405946/android-emulator-set-gps-geolocation)**

1. Run app in Android emulator.
2. Click on the ellipsis (...) in the toolbar.
3. Edit the coordinates in the newly opened settings under Location.

There's also a command line alternative for Android [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator) using `telnet` and the `geo fix` command.

Or, you can do as ashutosh pandey suggests and test on a real device.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for letting me know how to fix this issue so I can test my geolocation!

Comment: This isn't working on ios. I still get my current location no matter what.

Comment: @Goehybrid restart the emulator to see the revised location.

Answer (score 0):

- Run the Android emulator
- Click on the three dots (...)
- set preferred location under Location settings.